# Start capturing on right and not left

Tags: regex

I have the following RE that needs to match starting on the end of the string.

Strings:

```
AAA. A ZZZ-X37

AAA 4X X9 A ZZZ-X37

AAA 4X A ZZZ-X37
```

RE:

`^(?<g1>\s?[a-zA-Z\.]*)(?<g2>\s?[a-zA-Z\d]*)?(?<g3>\s?[a-zA-Z\d]*)?(?<g4>\s?[a-zA-Z]*)(?:\s?(?P<CAPT1>[A-Z]*)(?:-)?(?P<CAPT2>[\w\d]*)(?:-.{2})?)$`

CAPT1 needs to capture the ZZZ on all the cases, but on example #1 and #3 its not getting it.
I tried making the g2 and g3 group optional, but didnt seem to make a difference.

My idea now is to start matching by the end of the string, so that would capture what I need first, but if g2 and g3 could all be optional, then I would prefer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor the pattern to make the patterns inside optional groups obligatory:

```php
^(?<g1>\s*[a-zA-Z.]+)(?<g2>\s+[a-zA-Z\d]+)?(?<g3>\s+[a-zA-Z\d]+)?(?<g4>\s?[a-zA-Z]*)(?:\s+(?P<CAPT1>[A-Z]+)-(?P<CAPT2>\w+)(?:-.{2})?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8RpYao/2).

Basically, rather than having a chain of `(x?a*)?(x?a*)` etc. you can use `(x+a+)?`. For example, `(?<g2>\s?[a-zA-Z\d]*)?` turns into `(?<g2>\s+[a-zA-Z\d]+)?` to make sure this part is different from the one that was matched by `(?<g1>\s*[a-zA-Z.]+)`, i.e. so that they could not match at the same location in the string.

I kept `(?<g4>\s?[a-zA-Z]*)` intact but if you have further issues follow the same logic, and replace it with `(?<g4>\s+[a-zA-Z]+)?`.